# Execution of same statement in vb.net for hours in visual studio

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am running a small program in vb.net in which massive amount of data is handled.
Sometimes the program is running without any issues. But sometime the same line 'ulAutoInsertedID = oCommand.ExecuteScalar()' is executed for hours. It is not moving to the next line. can i know the reason for it. This is the query where it is getting struck.

```
        oCommand.Connection = oConn
        oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM " + Settings.sTO_SCHEMA_NAME + "." + s_TableName
        ulAutoInsertedID = oCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the database server. 
Is it a shared resource?

Comment: Yes it is a shared resource

Comment: Other than changing your db provider, you might also consider using an asynchronous query so your code would keep doing other useful things while a separate thread would wait for the db server to return.

Comment: I will be having about 90 records. For each record the saving occurs for about 6 to 7 tables and using this command the 6 to 7 tables will be getting updated. I mean for this case the asynchronous query will work perfectly ?